# Best way to pause application in for statement

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I want my set delay in my for statement for each 1 seconds. thats what I did.

```
Dim dueTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
 for i=1 to 500

While DateTime.Now < dueTime

Application.DoEvents()

                    End While
    'the code

        next i
```

Since I have 10 simultaneous process like this I noticed that the cpu usage in my system raised to 70 percent. I ran the code without delay and it became only 10 percent. Is there other ways to to that?

Note: I can find my way with C# or VB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `Await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))`

Comment: Whould you tell me how to use await  in for statement?

Comment: The same way you use `Await` anywhere else, assuming you're using a version of the language that supports `Await`.